# Apache MOD_REWRITE for subdomain

Tags: apache-2.2, domain, mod-rewrite, url, url-routing

**Summary**

I have 2 servers, 1 Production & 1 Development

**Problem**

I want to keep the servers URLS the same in the code.  The production server will be **blah.com** but I want the development server to be **dev.blah.com**.  The hard coded urls on both the sites are **blah.com**.

So when accessing **dev.blah.com** how would I be able to use Apache to keep me on this site without redirecting to **blah.com**?  Am I looking at this correctly or is there something else I should be doing?

Comment: You should not hard code server names in code. Ever. Use relative URLs or make the base URL a configuration variable.

Answer (score 2):

If your site sends out URLs from blah.com and you click on your browser on those URLs, your browser will send you to blah.com and there's nothing you can rewrite to avoid that.

The solution for this issue is to make the base URL configurable for your site or just use relative paths in the URLs (i.e use `/section/` instead of `http://blah.com/section/`.

Comment: You can technically have the site in blah.com check the referrer and redirect to dev.blah.com if you came from there, but that will probably break a lot of things if you site isn't strictly static.